# Filter website data using roles in Angular

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot, angular7

I want to use login roles in Angular SPA application (everything is run on the client side) with Spring Security and Spring Boot. 
When user roles are added to restrict for example displaying data 
can experienced developer edit the code restricting the data based on the role and display the restricted code violating the role restriction?

Is there some way to prevent this and secure the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to create a custom structural directive `roleType` that will show and hide data based on roleType of the user.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-custom-structural-directive)

**roletype.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[roleType]'
})
export class RoleTypeDirective {

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private dataService: DataService) {

  }

  currentRoleType: string = this.dataService.currentRoleType;

  @Input() set roleType(roleType: string) {
    if (roleType.includes(this.currentRoleType)) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
    else {
      this.vcRef.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button *roleType="'AMU'">View</button>
<button *roleType="'AM'">Edit</button>
<button *roleType="'A'">Delete</button>
```

Where A- Admin, M- Moderator and U-stands for User.